# SharpEye error when trying to read a .tiff

Tags: windows-error-reporting, handwriting-recognition

Opening a `.tiff` (or monochrome `.bmp`) file with SharpEye, then using `Read`→`Read` in the menu throws an error `Failed/unable to write to BMP file`.

Comment: What did the software developers say when you asked them about an issue with their product?

Comment: @Tetsujin Nothing